# PHPUnit and multi-processing testing

Tags: php, phpunit, fork, multiprocessing

I am writing a library for doing multi-processing (forking) and would like to test it with PHPUnit.

So far I came up with following scenario:

- Making the process to be tested to run itself as a forked process - so if something goes wrong, the main process where PHPUnit is running would not stuck forever (I use some kind of time limit, after which the tested child process is killed).
- In the tested process and any other sub-processes created by it I do log all my actions (performed work, received and sent signals, etc) in a some kind of formatted log, which can be later easy processed
- After all work is done in the main process, where PHPUnit testing is done, I do read and process the created logs and to my assertions - check if expected actions were performed or not.

Are there any would good/better techniques how to do the testing compared to my scenario?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at how I'm testing [Spork](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/spork/blob/master/tests/Spork/Test/ProcessManagerTest.php). The key is to call `pcntl_wait()` before running your assertions.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend that you separate the testing of the forking from the testing of the work done in the forked process(es). For example, say your program processes a directory recursively by spawning a child process for each subdirectory and then processing the files in its own directory itself.

Instead of processing a large directory tree in its entirety and analyzing the resulting output--created only for the tests no less--have tests for processing a file, tests for spawning a child with a directory, a test that directories are detected, etc.

Your tests will become easier as you shrink the size of the system each must test to small units of work. When you get to testing that children are spawned, you could mock out the system call if you place it into its own method.

This covers a lot at a very high level. Ask for specifics if you need more details.

Comment: I know what you mean - but in this specific case I am testing the system, which does the forking and sends/received signals between different processes - telling them to quit, restart, etc. So each sub-process can be mocked to do very simple things just for the unit-testing, my purpose is to test either "manager" of sub-processes is working properly. So I guess in this case I still need to do real forking

Comment: @Laimoncijus - Logging to a file and validating the results seems like a good method. The trick will be ordering since all those processes will be running concurrently. If you use signalling to make them run in sequence you wouldn't be forking. ;) You could always sort the log for doing the diff.